# Is this dynamic graph problem solvable?

Tags: graphs, data-structures

I came up with following subproblem while working on another problem. Can someone confirm if its a recognized problem. I have spent months but couldn't make any progress.

---

Design a data structure that maintains a directed graph. A node with node_id=0 is created by default, having no edges. The data-structure supports following queries:

1. Create() : Create a new node with node_id assigned from an auto-incrementing counter. Add a directed edge from node-0 to this new node; return node_id of new node.
2. Add(x, y) : Add a directed edge from node-x to node-y. Ignore if there is already an edge from x to y.
3. Delete(x, y) : Delete the directed edge from node-x to node-y and also delete all the nodes (and their edges) of graph which are not reachable from node-0. return the list of deleted edges and nodes.

All queries should work in amortized complexity O(log(N)), where N is the number of nodes in the graph at the time of query.

PS: Its not a homework problem (obviously).

Comment: Do you know the number of vertices at the beganing?

Comment: To add node should do `create()` first then `add(x,y)`?

Comment: 1). Initially there is only one vertex (node_id=0).

2). Yes. add(x, y) assumes both node-x and node-y already exists.

Comment: I have kind of solution but the `delete()` O (N lg N)

Comment: So after every `delete()` operation, the graph will remove all nodes that are not connected to 0 directly, rigth?

Comment: Right.. It will remove all the nodes which are not reachable from 0.

Comment: Ok, let see then

Comment: This kind of problem is recognized as "single source reachability for dynamic directed graphs".

Comment: What's the best data structure you've found so far?  Do you have any reason to expect that $O(\log n)$ time for all operations is achievable?  That seems optimistic.

Comment: I couldn't find anything better than trivial solution - recomputing reachability on delete. It works in O(N + M), so next thing one would expect is `O(log n)` by compromising some complexity in edge updation.
The same problem can be solved in `O(log^2(n))` for undirected graph and `O(1)` for DAG.
https://team.inria.fr/erable/files/2014/11/connectivity.pdf

Comment: The most challenging part the `delete` operation in `O (lg N)`